# report generating empty lines with 0's

Tags: php, html, mysql

Not too long ago I wrote some code that runs a query against a MySQL DB and then iterates through the results putting them in tables a sends the results out in an email.

Lately, I get the mail in the morning and once and awhile I have a random empty row with a "0" in it as seen here:

[image]

When I run my query there is NEVER any 0's or empty rows in it. The data always comes back clean. So, I'm figuring this must be in my loop somehow. I dunno. Anyways...below is my if statement:

```
if ($result_count = $conn->query($sql_count)) {
    while($row = $result_count->fetch_assoc()) {
        $message .= '<tr style="white-space: normal;line-height: normal;font-weight: normal;font-variant: normal;font-style: normal;text-align: start;">
                  <td style="border-width: 1px;padding: 8px;border-style: solid;border-color: #666666;background-color: #ffffff;display: table-cell;vertical-align: inherit;">'.$row["number"].'</td>
                  <td style="border-width: 1px;padding: 8px;border-style: solid;border-color: #666666;background-color: #ffffff;display: table-cell;vertical-align: inherit;">'.$row["u_name"].'</td>
                  <td style="border-width: 1px;padding: 8px;border-style: solid;border-color: #666666;background-color: #ffffff;display: table-cell;vertical-align: inherit;">'.$row["code"].'</td>
                  <td style="border-width: 1px;padding: 8px;border-style: solid;border-color: #666666;background-color: #ffffff;display: table-cell;vertical-align: inherit;">'.$row["acode"].'</td>
                  <td style="border-width: 1px;padding: 8px;border-style: solid;border-color: #666666;background-color: #ffffff;display: table-cell;vertical-align: inherit;">'.$row["name"].'</td>
                  <td style="border-width: 1px;padding: 8px;border-style: solid;border-color: #666666;background-color: #ffffff;display: table-cell;vertical-align: inherit;">'.$row["success"].'</td>
                  <td style="border-width: 1px;padding: 8px;border-style: solid;border-color: #666666;background-color: #ffffff;display: table-cell;vertical-align: inherit;">'
        .$row["comment"].
            '</td>
                  </tr>';
    }
} else {
    echo "No work orders have been entered into the system today.";
}
```

Anyone have any ideas? If you need to see anything else let me know. Hoping someone can spot what I can't seem to see.

**EDIT:**

I will add more here and hope it clears it up. So, today I got another report and again more rows with zero's. It seems to be happening almost every day now...

[image]

Here is the output if I run the query:

[image]

Here is how the table is built:

[image]

And finally...here is the page used to produce the email (minus all the CSS)

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>

   <head>
   <title>Daily Report</title>
<meta charset=utf-8>
   </head>

   <body>
    <?php 
    require 'db/spoc_config.php';
    ?>
    <?php

    $conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql_count = "
    select number, name, u_name, code, acode, success, comment from forms where Day(date) = Day(CURDATE()) and Month(date) = Month(CURDATE()) and year(date) = YEAR(CURDATE());";
    $result_count = $conn->query($sql_count);
    $count = mysqli_fetch_row($result_count);
    $str_count = implode($count);

    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
    $today = date('l, jS F Y');
    $week = date('W');
    $to = "someemail@email.com";
    $subject = "WOR: Daily Report " . $today;        
    $heading = "<b>Work Order Daily Report: </b>";

    $message = "<h2>" . $heading . " " . $today . "</h2>"; 
    $message .= '<table>';
    $message .= '
     <thead>
     <tr>
     <th>WO#</th>
     <th>Engineer Name</th>
     <th>Site</th>
     <th>Airline</th>        
     <th>WO Description</th>
     <th>Status</th>
     <th>Comment</th>
     </tr>
     <tr></tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
     ';

     if ($result_count = $conn->query($sql_count)) {
     while($row = $result_count->fetch_assoc()) {
     $message .= '<tr>
      <td>'.$row["number"].'</td>
      <td>'.$row["u_name"].'</td>
      <td>'.$row["code"].'</td>
      <td>'.$row["acode"].'</td>
      <td>'.$row["name"].'</td>
      <td>'.$row["success"].'</td>
      <td>'
      .$row["comment"].
      '</td>
      </tr>';
            }
        } else {
            echo "No work orders have been entered into the system today.";
        }

     $message .= '</tbody></table>';         
     $header = "From:someemail@email.com \r\n";
     $header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
     $header .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";

     $retval = mail ($to,$subject,$message,$header,'-fsomeemail@email.com');

     $conn->close();
    ?>
```

OK...so I've determined that the data has the zero's in it. So, what's been displayed is proper....but I can't figure out what's causing the zero's. I've included below the form page, as I assume it must be how it's being generated. hoping someone can see the problem:

```
    <?php
require 'db/spoc_config.php';

$link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

if (!$link){
    die('Could not connect due to: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $link);

if (!$db_selected){
    die('Can\'t use: ' . DB_NAME . ': ' . mysql_error());
}

$u_name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['u_name']);
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$code = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['code']);
$acode = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['acode']);
$source = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['source']);
$number = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['number']);
$assess = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['assess']);
$asse = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['asse']);
$success = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['success']);
$status = implode ("|" , $_POST['status']);
$comment = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['comment']);
$nchangenum = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['nchangenum']);
$pchangenum = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pchangenum']);
$date = date("Y-m-d");
$sql = "INSERT INTO forms (u_name, name, code, acode, source, number, assess, asse, success, status, comment, nchangenum, pchangenum, date) VALUES ('$u_name', '$name', '$code', '$acode', '$source', '$number', '$assess', '$asse', '$success', '$status', '$comment', '$nchangenum', '$pchangenum', '$date')";

if (!mysql_query($sql)){
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_close();
?>

<html>
<?php require 'head.php' ?>
<body>
<div>
<div>
<div></div>
<h3>
Airport Operations Workorder Repository
</h3>
    </div>
<?php include 'nav.php';?>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
            </div>
            <div>
<?php
session_start();

$username = $_SESSION['username'];

if($_SESSION['username']){
    echo "<div><p class='bold_user'>Welcome, " . $_SESSION['username'] . ".</p><a href='logout.php'>(logout)</a></div>";
}
else die("<div class='reg'>You must be logged in.</div>");
?>
<div class="container">
<div class="outer">
<div class="inner">
<div class="centered">
<?php echo "<div class='loginerr'>You have successfully entered Work Order # " . $number . ". Please return to <a href='page.php'>the previous page</a> to enter more.</div>" ?>            
            </div>
            <div>
            </div>
            <div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i am sure it's coming from db itself. BTW you can apply a check and remove it

Comment: Is it possible that your data breaks your html? If so take a look at `htmlspecialchars()`

Comment: Your loop looks fine, and since you're only seeing that phantom row "once in a while" then it suggests the issue is with the data and not your loop. Can you provide the query that's being run to select that data?

Comment: Can you try to create a [mcve]? It doesn't look like there's enough info here to answer this. (By the way, all that inline style probably doesn't need to be part of the MCVE, and omitting it will make your question easier to read.)

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding try below steps :-

1. Check the Data Type of Number filed in the database .Also  please
2. Check if there is any white space in the data in the database.
   Put trim in the code
3. Check the Count of total rows being returned using the result set .

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your $message in a validation if():

```
if($row["number"] && $row["number"] > 0)
{
    $message .= '<tr style="white-space: normal;line-height: normal;font-weight: normal;font-variant: normal;font-style: normal;text-align: start;">
                  <td style="border-width: 1px;padding: 8px;border-style: solid;border-color: #666666;background-color: #ffffff;display: table-cell;vertical-align: inherit;">'.$row["number"].'</td>
                  <td style="border-width: 1px;padding: 8px;border-style: solid;border-color: #666666;background-color: #ffffff;display: table-cell;vertical-align: inherit;">'.$row["u_name"].'</td>
                  <td style="border-width: 1px;padding: 8px;border-style: solid;border-color: #666666;background-color: #ffffff;display: table-cell;vertical-align: inherit;">'.$row["code"].'</td>
                  <td style="border-width: 1px;padding: 8px;border-style: solid;border-color: #666666;background-color: #ffffff;display: table-cell;vertical-align: inherit;">'.$row["acode"].'</td>
                  <td style="border-width: 1px;padding: 8px;border-style: solid;border-color: #666666;background-color: #ffffff;display: table-cell;vertical-align: inherit;">'.$row["name"].'</td>
                  <td style="border-width: 1px;padding: 8px;border-style: solid;border-color: #666666;background-color: #ffffff;display: table-cell;vertical-align: inherit;">'.$row["success"].'</td>
                  <td style="border-width: 1px;padding: 8px;border-style: solid;border-color: #666666;background-color: #ffffff;display: table-cell;vertical-align: inherit;">'
        .$row["comment"].
            '</td>
                  </tr>';
}
else
{
    // skip this line - do nothing
}
```